# is my method of performing production testing before rolling update in kubernetes correct?

Tags: kubernetes

Here is an example cluster setup that matches my production cluster:

```
Ingress rule abc.com > Service-AB > Pod-A, Pod-B > cluster-A, cluster-B > image-0.1.1

Ingress rule xyz.com > Service-CD > Pod-C, Pod-D > cluster-C, cluster-D > image-1.3.2
```

Imagine I need to update cluster1's image to `v0.1.2`, to do this I can just change the deployment manifest and `apply` it to perform a rolling update but before that I want to do an e2e test in production cluster to make sure the new image, behaves as expected there.

To accomplish this, I create a [Pod Spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#pod-v1-core) having the new image version together with a new service that selects only that new pod and an ingress rule to reach this new service. It looks like following,

```
Ingress rule abc.com/update > Service-Z > Pod-Z > cluster-Z > image-0.1.2
```

Now I point my e2e test to the endpoint `abc.com/update`, once successful, I delete the new ingress rule, service and pod and follow the normal process of rolling update by updating the deployment with new container image version and performing an `apply`.

Is it a correct way to do testing in production cluster, can there be a better (easier) way?

Answer (score 2):

I think it varies depending on the technology that you are using. Given your case, which is using plain kubernetes. I would use a proxy in between to do the A/B testing. Here is the description:

**Before upgrade:**
Ingress rule abc.com -> svc-proxy -> pod-proxy --> svc-my-pod (v1.0.0)

**After upgrade (A/B) testing:** 
Ingress rule abc.com -> svc-proxy -> pod-proxy --> svc-my-pod-1 (v1.0.0)
                      | 
                      --> svc-my-pod-2 (v1.1.0)

**Fully upgraded**
Ingress rule abc.com -> svc-proxy -> pod-proxy -> my-pod (v1.1.0)



Note that in the A/B testing phase you would have to add an upstream with weights (if using nginx) to emulate the desired weighted policy.

```
upstream dynamic {
    server pod-proxy-1      weight=2;
    server pod-proxy-2      weight=4;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://dynamic;
    }
}
```

### Using services and endpoints to switch between pods

Have a yaml with v1 called pod-v1. You would define its match label like the following yaml:

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pod-v1
```

Have a yaml with v2 called pod-v2. You would define its match label like the following yaml:

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pod-v2
```

Then you can easily change routing between the pods by changing the selector of a service. Like the following yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pod
  labels:
    app: pod
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8000"
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: pod-v1
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Note that to route the traffic to v2 you would just change the selector to match the label pod-v2.

```
selector:
  app: pod-v2
```

Comment: sorry but I didn't quite get that, are you talking about some specific ingress technology? what is service and pod proxy? also I am not a/b testing but testing in production the newer version just before deploying it.

Comment: Note it is the same logic you were following. Obviously ingress is a common kubernetes ingress, say nginx if you want. What I am trying to show you is how to do the canary deployment and divide traffic between the v1.0.0 and v1.1.0. That is what the weight in the proxy stands for.

Comment: ok I understood what you tried to say, the point is I didn't want to split the traffic at all because the traffic isn't the e2e test I need to perform on the newer version, what I required that I point my test to the new version, successfully test it and then move on to normal upgrade.
I found out that ingress-nginx's canary deplpyment method might help here, i could perhaps use a special 'header value' in my e2e test request and ingress would send those to the newer version. Your reference to canary was correct, thank you.
I'll write my own answer after implementing it and accept.

Comment: Given your description I have a super easy answer for you I have actually used at my job. Let me describe it.

Comment: Check the latest edit. Specifically the title "Using services and endpoints to switch between pods"

Comment: I'd never do that to a service that is exposed to live traffic. You're simply switching the live production service to point to another version that's need to be tested first? Rather than this I'd simply create another service in the ingress, create an ingress rule (one time configuration) to send traffic based on particular header value to the new service and point the new service to the version that need testing (like v2). Then I'll point my tests to ingress IP, set a header like 'production-test'= true. Ingress will read the header and direct request to v2 service.

Comment: If test passes, I'll be ready to do a rolling upgrade normally. Now whenever I need to test a newer version, I'll just edit my another service and don't have to touch the production service.

Comment: Obviously, the idea is that you build upon these k8s features or use a continuous delivery tool. The question wa about k8s remember?